# Save id of link clicked as a session

Tags: php, html, session

Lets start from the beginning. I have a database which stores a links the name which is placed over the link and auto increment ids for each link. My code brings up all of the links in the database when the link is clicked it takes me to the default page for each link. but heres the problem. the content on the page has to depend on the id of the link which is clicked. is there a way to save the id of the link which is clicked as a session so i can view the content on the next page.

**My code so far**

```
   <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "root";
    $dbname = "score";


    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
         die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT id, name, description FROM all_scores ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
             echo "<p></p>";
             echo "<a href=score2/view.php>". $row["name"]. "</a>";
                 echo "<p>". $row["description"]. "</p>";
         }
    } else {
         echo "0 results";
    }

    $conn->close();
?>
```

how can i save the if of the link clicked as a session. the link is default so it never changes but the name description and id have an id and the id from them is what i need saved.
i have looked everywhere and i need an answer or something to help me.

Comment: You can add with AJAX. But I din't find any id for your link.

Comment: There are multiple approaches. Why not simply add `?id=X` to your link and fetch it on the next page using `$_GET['id']`?

Comment: could you go more indepth@Rick

Comment: @JensonMJohn its the id for the **name** which is placed on top of the link.

Answer (score 1):

You can append the `id` of the page to the link itself. So your `while` loop should be like this:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<a href=score2/view.php?pageid=" . $row["id"] . ">". $row["name"]. "</a>";
    echo "<p>". $row["description"]. "</p>";
}
```

And on **view.php** page catch the `pageid` like this:

```
$pageid = $_GET['pageid'];

// Now display the page
```